# The same data are not equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to compare the data on the identity. And I know that they are the same. This test confirms this:

```
it "should pass" do
  a = []
  b = []
  a << backlink_1.id
  b.concat( results('fulltext_search', ["right"], 'like').map(&:id) )

  b == a
end
```

tests pass

```
Finished in 3.24 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
Done.
```

but if i use `.should ==`
in tests, they fall

```
it "should pass too" do
  results('fulltext_search', ["right"]).map(&:id).should == [backlink_1.id]
end

Failures:

  1) Search::Mapper::Backlinks::ToElasticsearch#build_search_object [defaults] first spec
     Failure/Error: results('fulltext_search', ["right"]).map(&:id).should == [backlink_1.id]
       expected: ["5395942e8cb323e711000002"]
            got: ["5395942e8cb323e711000002"] (using ==)
       Diff:
     # ./spec/lib/search/mapper/backlinks/to_elasticsearch_spec.rb:46:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.2 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Logs show that data same.
Why, then raise error?

Comment: The first spec does not test anything. You could add a `'foo' == 'bar'` instead of `a` and `b` and still make it pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, off, your first spec confirms nothing: it is doing the comparison but then does nothing with the result of it.

Your second spec does show that the output of `inspect` is the same in both cases. The next step would be to look at the actual object instances in more detail to check that they are actually the same. For example perhaps they are instances of different classes, and the `==` method on one of them is checking that the class is the same.

Comment: and if I just want to compare two arrays. why I can not use this test?

Comment: That's down to the objects in the arrays - you need to investigate further to establish why they are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

As for array comparisons RSpec doesn't quite work with plain `==` but it has an specific `match_array` for these cases, try something like:

```
results('fulltext_search', ["right"]).map(&:id).should match_array([backlink_1.id])
```